# Solutions of $a^{b^c}=c^{b^a}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have recently come across the equation $a^{b^c}=c^{b^a}$ for $a,b,c \in \mathbb N$. Is it true that the only solutions to this equality is $a=c$, $b \in \mathbb N$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proof relies on multiple uses of [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) for $a\ge 1$, $n\in\mathbb N$:

$$a^n\ge 1+n(a-1)$$

WLOG suppose $c>a$.

$$\log_b \log_a a^{b^c} = \log_b \log_a c^{b^a}$$
$$c = \log_b (b^a\log_a c) = a+\log_b\log_ac$$
$$a^{b^{c-a}}=c$$

But
$$a^{b^{c-a}}\ge1+b^{c-a}(a-1)\ge1+(a-1)(1+(c-a)(b-1))=a+(a-1)(b-1)(c-a)$$

For $a>1 \lor b>1$, $a+(a-1)(b-1)(c-a)>a+(c-a)=c$, a contradiction.

So we must have $a=b=1$, leading to $$1=1^{1^c} = c^{1^1}=c$$

Hence we cannot have $a\ne c$.

Answer (score 2):

Beside the case $a=1$ which implies $c=1$, considering the prime factorisation of $a, \, c$ there must be positive integers $n\ge2, \, A, \, C$ with $a=n^A, \, c=n^C$ so that $A/C=b^{n^A-n^C}$. If $b=1$, $a=c$. Without loss of generality an $a\ne c$ solution satisfies $A>C$: write $A=Cb^k$ so $k=n^{Cb^k}-n^C\ge C(b^k-1)\ge Ck$ and $C=1, \, b=2, \, k=1,\,1=n^2-n$, so there are no solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Since when $a=1$, $c=1$ which implies $a=c$, let's assume WLOG that $c \geq a \geq 2$. Since $a^{b^c}=c^{b^a}$ have solutions only if $a$ and $c$ have the same prime factor exponent ratio, further assume that $c=a^m$ for $m \in \mathbb Q$ and $m>1$. (If $m=0$ then the only solution is $a=c=1$, if $0<m<1$ then flipping $a$ and $c$ would result in $m>1$, and if $m=1$ then $a=c$ is already implied.)  That means that $c\geq4$, since $a^m=2$ and $a^m=3$ have no solutions.  Also, when $b=1$, $a^{1^c}=a$ and $c^{1^b}=c$, so $a=c$ implies. Therefore, assume that $b\geq2$. Then, the equation  can be simplified as below:$$a^{b^c}=c^{b^a}$$$$a^{b^{a^m}}=(a^m)^{b^a}$$$$b^{a^m}=mb^a$$$$b^{a^m-a}=m$$$$b=m^\frac{1}{a^m-a}$$Now, consider two functions: $$f(x)=x^\frac{1}{a^x-a}$$$$g(x)=m^\frac{1}{x^m-x}$$We need to show that (1) $f(x)<2$ for $x>1$ when $a\geq4$, and that (2) $g(x)<2$ for $x>4$ when $m>1$.

For condition (1), consider the derivative of $f(x)$:$$f'(x)=\frac{x^\frac{1}{a^x-a}}{x(a^x-a)^2}(a^x-a-xa^x\ln{a}\ln{x})$$Since $\frac{x^\frac{1}{a^x-a}}{x(a^x-a)^2}$ is always positive, consider $h(x)=a^x-a-xa^x\ln{a}\ln{x}$.$$h'(x)=-a^x\ln a\ln x(x\ln a+1)<0$$Therefore, $h(x)$ is always decreasing. Since $h(1)=0$, $h(x)<0$ for $x>1$, so $f'(x)<0$ for $x>1$, and thus $f(x)$ is decreasing for $x>1$.

For condition (2), since $(x+k)^m-x^m>k+xm-xm=k$ for $x>4$, $m>1$ and $k>0$,$$x^m<(x+k)^m-k$$$$x^m-x<(x+k)^m-x-k$$$$\frac{1}{x^m-x}>\frac{1}{(x+k)^m-x-k}$$$$m^{\frac{1}{x^m-x}}>m^{\frac{1}{(x+k)^m-x-k}}$$$$g(x)>g(x+k)$$

Since conditions (1) and (2) and both true, it can be seen that for $m>1$ and $a>4$, $m^\frac{1}{a^m-a}<\lim_{m \to 1}m^\frac{1}{4^m-4}$.$$y=\lim_{m \to 1}m^\frac{1}{4^m-4}$$$$\ln y=\ln \lim_{m \to 1}m^\frac{1}{4^m-4}$$$$\ln y=\lim_{m \to 1}\frac{\ln m}{4^m-4}$$$$\ln y=\lim_{m \to 1}\frac{\frac{1}{m}}{4^m\ln4}$$$$\ln y=\frac{1}{8\ln2}$$$$y=e^\frac{1}{8\ln2}$$ Since $e^\frac{1}{8\ln2}<2$, $m^\frac{1}{a^m-a}<2$ for $m>1$ and $a>4$. Thus, $b<2$ which contradicts our initial assumption that $b\geq2$, so $m>1$ has no solutions. Similarly, by swapping $a$ and $c$ and repeating the same process, one can see that $0<m<1$ also has no solutions. Therefore, the only solutions to the equality is $a=c$, $b \in \mathbb N$.